# Power BI runs very slow for a same query which runs fast in Toad

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to import my data to power bi, which gives me the data as below PL/SQL:

```
SELECT
  A.WINDOW,
  A.ROUTE,
  A.WEBORDERNUM,
  min(A.SCANDATE)
FROM
  SCANNING A
WHERE
  (
   A.CARTONSTATUS  IN  ( 'DELIVERED','REFUSED' )
   AND
   ( A.SCANDATE  >TRUNC(SYSDATE)+1/24)
  )
 Group by
 A.WINDOW,
 A.ROUTE,
 A.WEBORDERNUM
```

I import the scanning table in power bi, and do the following steps:

[image]

Then I go to view my sql statement in Power BI, and It looks like that:

```
select "rows"."WEBORDERNUM" as "WEBORDERNUM",
    "rows"."ROUTE" as "ROUTE",
    "rows"."WINDOW" as "WINDOW",
    min("rows"."SCANDATE") as "Min Scan"
from 
(
    select "_"."SCANDATE",
        "_"."WEBORDERNUM",
        "_"."ROUTE",
        "_"."WINDOW"
    from "AIRCLIC_PROD"."CARTONTRACKING" "_"
    where "_"."SCANDATE" > TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-06-26 01:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') and ("_"."CARTONSTATUS" = 'DELIVERED' and "_"."CARTONSTATUS" is not null or "_"."CARTONSTATUS" = 'REFUSED' and "_"."CARTONSTATUS" is not null)
) "rows"
group by "WEBORDERNUM",
    "ROUTE",
    "WINDOW"
```

I think they are exactly the same, but I am not sure it takes more than 5 mins to import the data in power bi, but when I run the query in Toad, it only take last than 1 sec.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: The `where` clause has more conditions to check. Maybe try to remove the null checking?

Comment: the problem should come from scandate, it is a datetime format, not date.